# What are the most important hyperparameters to tune to optimize the training of a 3D U-NET used for pixel classification?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, hyperparameter-tuning

Leaving aside the training loss, the optimizer (ADAM), the number of U-NET blocks (tuned to a meaningful target receptive field for the problem) and the number of filters per layer (set to the maximum fitting in gpu memory for batch size = 1), what would be the most critical hyperparameters, and some sensible guidelines to tune them to achieve the best prediction accuracy without having to perform a multi-gpu extensive/expensive search for each problem?